# Looking up data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am attempting a simple lookup from a MySQL database. I am having no luck with any tutorials I read, most are trying to do something a lot more complex and I can't seam to narrow down the code!

I believe I have the database working as it is connecting to it without an error. However I can't seem to get the code right, this is what I have got so far... 
I am trying to get the `firstname` out of the database when referring to the `lastname`. There are 5 rows in the table.

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$dbname = "shipping";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT firstname WHERE lastname = 'Barack' FROM MyGuests";

{
    echo "Name: ".$rows['firstname']."<br/>";

}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `FROM MyGuests` is in the wrong place in your query

Comment: you haven't executed any sql in your code.

Comment: Test the query in phpmyadmin SQL tab to make sure you are getting the results you want, this helps me a lot.  Then add `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` to execute in your php script

Comment: nor have you looped over results; this besides other comments here. Whatever tutorial(s) you read, are either bad or you didn't follow them "to a T".

Comment: `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query would have produced a few errors and error reporting on `$rows` would have thrown you an undefined variable notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. The syntax of your query is incorrect.
2. You need to actually **execute** the query. All you're doing at the moment is assigning it as a string to a variable.

Update as follows:

```
$result = $conn->query( 'SELECT firstname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname = \'Barack\'' );

while( $guest = $result->fetch_object() )
{
    echo $guest->firstname.'<br />';
}
```

Notice the use of [`query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and [`fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

Comment: You could have saved yourself a few keystrokes `"SELECT firstname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname = 'Barack'"` ;-) why escape the quotes?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Force of habit and coding style. I always find single quotes to be cleaner (weird, I know), but just my style.

Comment: FWIW, I also find single quotes easier to work with when concatenating strings, too. It makes spotting concatenation a lot easier, especially for those pesky devs who use `echo "Hello $forename!"` in PHP ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "shipping";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname = 'Barack'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['firstname'] ;
}
?>
```

**OR** you can try using Object-oriented concept

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "shipping";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname = 'Barack'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['firstname'] ;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Why not maintain the OO nature of the code the OP has used?

Comment: @BenM both way added.

Comment: The first snippet you've posted does not construct a MySQLi object. It is still connecting via procedural means.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks mostly good *except* I see at least 3 problems:
1) Your SQL is incorrect. You would know this if you were to check the result of your query.
2) Your code does not actually use the sql you define to perform any query.
3) You don't fetch any records from your result after you run your query.

How about this:

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$dbname = "shipping";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT firstname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname = 'Barack'";
// you have to actually run a query with your sql and check if it works
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    // you may have more than one record with a matching last name so you loop
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "Name: " . $myrow["firstname"] . "</br>";
    }
} else {
    // something didn't work. NOTE: you shouldn't output errors on a production machine
    // write a log instead or something
    printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error);
}

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need to find not a strict match (names like 'ABarack' or 'Baracka'), use wildcards:

```
SELECT firstname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname like '%Barack%'
```

Comment: No, that's not the problem at all. Please see the other answers.